# VBA - MS Project - Assign single task to an Object variable after using "Find"

Tags: vba, ms-project

I need to programmatically make changes to a few tasks. The tasks that need changes have ID numbers in the Text10 field. I would like to avoid using a filter if possible since all of these ID numbers are different. And looping through all the tasks takes way too long since the project file is 10k+ lines. I'm not sure if "Find" is the correct method here.

**Question:**

Is there a way to find the task using Text10 and assign is to a "Task" object so that I can then manipulate it?
The below doesn't work but can hopefully get the point across:

```
Sub test()

Dim t As Task

Set t = Find("Text10", "equals", "A1044Fh82")
t.SetField pjTaskDuration, 0


End Sub
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.find) method returns True if a matching value is found, and if so, the active selection is moved to the first matching task. So check the result of the Find method and then use the [ActiveCell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.activecell) property to get a reference to the task:

```
If Application.Find("Text10", "equals", "A1044Fh82") Then
    Dim t As Task
    Set t = Application.ActiveCell.Task
    t.Duration = 0
End If
```